# js object values inside array to string

Tags: javascript

**The code works** fine for changing the type of `value` to string in all cases.
But i was wondering if there are better/cleaner ways to do it even using lodash.

```
const dummyResult = [
    { id: 1, value: false },
    { id: 2, value: true },
    { id: 3, value: 'text' }
]

for (let i = 0; i < dummyResult.length; i++) {
    if (typeof (dummyResult[i].value) === 'boolean') {
        dummyResult[i].value = dummyResult[i].value.toString()
    }
}
```

**Desired result:**

```
 dummyResult = [
    { id: 1, value: 'false'},
    { id: 2, value: 'true' },
    { id: 3, value: 'text' }
]
```

Comment: What is "better" that is personal opinion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is best suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Satpal It is okay to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use forEach:

```js
const dummyResult = [
    { id: 1, value: false },
    { id: 2, value: true },
    { id: 3, value: 'text' }
]

dummyResult.forEach(e => typeof e.value === 'boolean' && (e.value = e.value.toString()));

console.log(dummyResult);
```

But I think you have not to check if it's boolean or not:

```js
const dummyResult = [
    { id: 1, value: false },
    { id: 2, value: true },
    { id: 3, value: 'text' }
]

dummyResult.forEach(e => e.value = e.value.toString());

console.log(dummyResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean shorter, this is an approach

```js
const dummyResult = [
    { id: 1, value: false },
    { id: 2, value: true },
    { id: 3, value: 'text' }
]

console.log(
  dummyResult.map(a=>{return{id: a.id, value: a.value.toString()}})
)
```

Comment: Use of map here is wrong.

Comment: You save a few bytes when omitting `{ return`

Comment: did you remove all the spaces to make it look as concise as possible? :D

Comment: @JonasW. I know, just was to be clear, i could do `a=>({id: a.id, value: a.value.toString())}` and save some bytes but this is not codegolf xD

Comment: or you could even do `a => ({ ...a, value: String(a.value) })`.

Comment: @epascarello why you think the use of map is wrong in this example?

Comment: @MarvinK because it doesn't change the initial object?

Comment: @MarvinK Possibly because map creates a new object instead modifying the existing one.

Comment: Unless OP wants a copy, it should be forEach altering the same object. A lot of time I see people using map, just to avoid 4 keystrokes. Other problem with the code is it will convert items that are not booleans so that may be an issue compared to what the OP stated.

Comment: @epascarello that is why I said shorter. OP said he wanted a cleaner way yo do it, i just proposed one where a new object is created. I dont see why my answer is wrong

Comment: In most cases it shouldn't be a problem to write the new object to another variable. I also think map is a good solution for this.

Comment: I did not downvote, my personal opinion that map is the wrong thing to use here. I could open a window with a hammer. It works, just not how I would open a window.

Comment: I mean if you are going for short, that drop the return and braces and you have even less.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a `forEach` to loop over the array and convert the value of `value` property to string:

```js
const dummyResult = [
    { id: 1, value: false },
    { id: 2, value: true },
    { id: 3, value: 'text' }
]

var res = [];
dummyResult.forEach((obj) => {
  obj.value = obj.value.toString();
  res.push(obj);
});

console.log(res);
```